# CSS links precedence

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been searching and reading about CSS precedence and I think I have the correct code, but it not works.
I want to have all the links in blue except for the ones that have the class='green'. The CSS code is:

```
a.green :link{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.green :visited{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
}   
a:visited {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
        color: orange;
        font-style: italic;
}
```

But the result is that all the links continue in blue.
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: You need to use classes or id's to the links so they can be identified. Such as `class="className"` or `id="idName"`

Comment: @Dave: Isn't that what he's already doing?

Comment: @BoltClock not in the html i suspect

Comment: @Dave: Hm, fair enough. I just spotted a different issue, though.

Comment: @BoltClock might want to add the HTML example in your answer just to cover all bases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces:

```
a.green:link{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.green:visited{
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Otherwise you end up looking for `:link`/`:visited` elements *within* `a.green` elements, which doesn't make sense.